# � char returned from Google currency API

Tags: php, google-api

Background:

I've created a website that displays currency rates from various countries.  I use Google's currency converter API to perform the calculations.

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?h1=en&q=9999gbp=?usd

Notice the query I have passed in e.g. `9999 Great British Pounds` to `United States Dollars`.

The API returns:

`{lhs: "9999 British pounds",rhs: "15 769.4229 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}`

Google has separated the `15 769.4229` with white space between the `5` and the `7`.

This causes a problem when I return the results of a calculation on my site as the white space char is replaced with the � symbol.

See screen shot below:

[image]

Any ideas what this symbol is called so I can attempt to remove it?

```
<?php

// Check to ensure that form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['amount'], $_POST['from'], $_POST['to'])) {
    $amount = trim($_POST['amount']);
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];

    try {
        $conversion = currency_convert($googleCurrencyApi, $amount, $from, $to);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Check URL has been formed 
    if ($conversion == false) {
        echo 'Sorry, something went wrong';
    } else {
        echo $conversion[0], ' = ', $conversion[1];
    }

}

function currency_convert($googleCurrencyApi, $amount, $from, $to) {

    $result = file_get_contents($googleCurrencyApi . $amount . $from . '=?' . $to);
    $expl = explode('"', $result);

    if ($expl[1] == '' || $expl[3] == '') {
        throw new Exception('An error has occured.  Unable to get file contents');
    } else {
        return array(
            $expl[1],
            $expl[3]
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Here's my code so far at the moment, so you get the idea behind my logic.

Comment: I'm guessing that the issue is just the encoding. Have you tried `utf8_decode ( string $data )`?

Comment: `$result = $conversion[0] . $conversion[1]; 
                echo utf8_decode($result);` still returns the mentioned char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably non-breaking space, try replacing into space:

```
$result = file_get_contents($googleCurrencyApi . $amount . $from . '=?' . $to);
$result = str_replace("\xA0", " ", $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code so that you're UTF8 decoding the data that's being returned from Google:

```
// Check URL has been formed 
    if ($conversion == false) {
        echo 'Sorry, something went wrong';
    } else {
        echo utf8_decode($conversion[0]), ' = ', utf8_decode($conversion[1]);
    }
```

I'm presuming that your default encoding is ISO-8859-1

### EDIT

(As per comments) The issue may be that you have been sent a null character. Try this:

```
$result = str_replace("\0", "", $result );
```

or

```
$result = str_replace("&#x0;", "", $result );
```

Comment: still returning the same.  Could this utf8_decode be overridden perhaps?

Comment: @keenProgrammer Added an additional approach

Answer (score 0):

After `str_replace` do:

```
$result_amt = utf8_decode($amount);
```

You will get the `?` character instead of space. So then use `str_replace` again to remove `?` character:

```
$result =str_replace("?","", $result_amt );
```